# How to debug request headers?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

Apache server running behind proxy server / load balancer. I wan't to access client's IP address with X-Forwarded-For but I can't find it.

I can confirm mod_remoteip loaded and configured.

```
[root~]# httpd -DDUMP_CONFIG | grep 'Forwarded'
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
[root~]# httpd -M | grep remote
remoteip_module (shared)
```

PHP's **$_SERVER** global

```
[USER] => apache
[HOME] => /usr/share/httpd
[FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
[UNIQUE_ID] => XEmuZocZaMSZxKpDrFwvfgAAAAA
[HTTP_HOST] => domain.com
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.116
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/.*;q=0.8
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.9
[PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
[SERVER_NAME] => domain.com
[SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.98.25
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 192.168.99.148
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
[REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
[CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
[CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
[SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/test.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 11255
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /test.php
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php
[PHP_SELF] => /test.php
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1548332646.3819
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1548332646
```

My question is, how can I confirm proxy server doesn't forward client's ip address in request header? Should it be in $_SERVER global? If not, how can log all request headers including custom headers?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can get the request headers as an array by `apache_request_headers()`.

There are rumours circulating, this function would not guarantee to return *all* headers. I could not verify that yet by finding any missing header, however, I could imagine that malformed lines might not be considered as headers.

Unfortunately there is no way to access the full raw request in PHP. You might want to do so using some CGI script language like Perl instead which provides access to the raw request.